# Future usage in python

Tags: python, future

---

Hello, i'm running a loop over multiple directory and sub directory to rename files. Each files is renamed based on some conditions and patterns.
Once i changed the name of my file to the one I want I can copy it to a new folder. But the process is long because at each loop my program wait that my file has been copied to continue.

Someone told me that there was something called **Future in JAVA** that allows the program to continue running while my files are copied.

Is there something equivalent in **Python** ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The disk is the bottleneck. Doing multiple copies at the same time is not likely to speed it up much.

Comment: But it sounds like you could just use multi-threading.